# Zero shot face similarity network

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

How do I create a deep learning model that can compare between two different faces and output the percentage of similarity between them. I want the model to be able to infer on classes of faces that it hasn’t been trained on. Essentially, predicting the similarity between faces of people the model has never seen before. As far as I’ve researched, I’ve been able to understand that this comes under the Zero-Shot Learning field of deep learning.

I’ve tried this on a siamese model(loss=binary crossentropy).
Unfortunately, the model was only able to predict on classes it was trained on. So I tried training a feature extraction model using triplet loss, but for some reason my model keeps showing a very high loss value.

P.S : Can this be done without transfer learning?

Comment: Essentially, you want to train your network not to output a direct score but rather a face embedding using a loss tailored for recognition, i.e. such that two embeddings of the same person are close in embedding space to each other. Then to compare two faces of people you have not seen during training you simply use the algorithm to obtain the embeddings of both face images. Then you compute the similarity, e.g. using cosine similarity. Some popular loss functions are MagFace and ArcFace, you can look up the papers / repos for more details.